# Where should a glossary be placed in a book?

Tags: copy-editing

I am writing a book for a technical industry. I'm planning on including a glossary, I wanted to know, should I place this at the beginning of the book or at the end of the book?

Answer (score 3):

There is no "correct" answer here. It really depends on what your goal is: if it's to inform the audience of terms before they start reading the main text, then it might make sense to place it in the "front matter." On the other hand, if you expect readers to consult it as needed when they're reading, then typically you'd place it at the end of the book with the appendices.

Comment: The publisher might also have something to say about this.

Comment: Yes, beginning or end as long as it is not missing...

Comment: Virtually all books I've seen with a glossary (easily in the hundreds --- including quite a few of my pre-university and university textbooks in most every subject) have the glossary at the end, usually before the index. However, the beginning might be a better choice for the OP's situation, but this decision requires a lot more specific information about the book, and it's likely that the decision is not entirely up to the OP (as @Buffy suggests).